# Unity - Object spins after collision

Tags: unity-game-engine

When my sphere collides with a tree of the terrain, the sphere spins around. I tried to freeze Z position und rotation, but it still spins after collision. Here is the move script:

```
player.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Speed is 10f. Thanks forwards.

Comment: Are you sure it's spinning on the Z axis? Have you tried freezing the other axes and seen it still spinning?  The way I imagine this happening from your question the object would be spinning on the Y axis.

Comment: When dealing with physics, you should move the **Rigidbody**, not the **Transform**, inside the **FixedUpdate** function, not the **Update** one.

Comment: Using Rigidbody instead of Transform didn't change anything. My mistake was only freezing the Z axis. I had to freeze all of axis (actually I don't have to freeze the Y axis, because after collision it just spins a little bit to the side, not a big deal).

Comment: @Echi Since you solved your problem please post your answer and select it as the right one.

Answer (score 1):

If you use physics on an object, do not change its position with its Transform component. You have to use its RigidBody component by either adding force to it or using `MovePosition` to move.

Comment: The problem was that I only freezes the Z axis instead all 3 of them. But I will keep this in mind, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A more realistic feel is if you detect collsion and then increase the angular drag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your current code but you need to go to your player's rigidbody component and set the Drag (NOT ANGULAR DRAG) to infinite by typing something like 999999999999999. You'll get 1e+37 inside the field.

This should resolve your issue for the most part. However, you may still run into another issue of "jittering" when you bump into walls from then forth. You may be able to live with it or you'll need to find a coding solution to work that out.

Let me know if you run into further issues.